# How to run vscode tunel without internet access

Tags: visual-studio-code, remote-access

I'm trying to run a VSCode tunnel on a VM which has no internet access using [THIS DOC](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/tunnels#_using-the-code-cli)

I've a connection issue at step 2, where vscode ask me to login on the remote host:

```
./code tunnel --accept-server-license-terms --verbose
*
* Visual Studio Code Server
*
* By using the software, you agree to
* the Visual Studio Code Server License Terms (https://aka.ms/vscode-server-license) and
* the Microsoft Privacy Statement (https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-US/privacystatement).
*
[2024-02-12 09:29:21] debug Starting tunnel with `code ./code tunnel --accept-server-license-terms --verbose`
[2024-02-12 09:29:21] debug starting as new singleton
[2024-02-12 09:29:21] debug No code server tunnel found, creating new one
[2024-02-12 09:29:21] debug Using file keychain storage due to: error reading keyring: Platform secure storage failure: no secret service provider or dbus session found
[2024-02-12 09:29:21] trace No token in keyring, getting a new one
? How would you like to log in to Visual Studio Code? ›
❯ Microsoft Account
  Github Account
```

Whereas I was expected it was the 4th step which ask me to log in...

Is there any option to postpone this login step? Or is the documentation out to date?

Answer (score 0):

Per [Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/dev-tunnels/overview)

This is classed as a “public preview”, meaning it may change with no notice, etc. Not recommended for production.

That said, did you choose an authentication method? If so, what happened? A brief web search using “vscode keyring” and “vscode token” gives lots of possible solutions, some of which should at least provide more data to work with.

Answer (score 0):

For how I understand it, authentication using an online account is required to be able to connect you to your own tunnels on the other end. That would mean internet access is required.

Maybe an VSCode SSH connection does work without internet.